# Moving cursor in PuTTY with mouse click?

Tags: ssh, mouse, putty

I've used PuTTY to connect via SSH to my FreeBSD- and Ubuntu-servers for several years, and I always move the cursor by using the keyboard. However, I wonder if it's possible to move the cursor in PuTTY by clicking on a target position with the mouse? It could be useful sometimes while editing files in nano etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This needs to be supported *by each program separately*, and I'm not sure if any shells support mouse...

In nano, add **`set mouse`** to your `~/.nanorc`.

Comment: Cool, it works through PuTTY in nano! :-)

Comment: [`:set mouse=a`](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_the_mouse_for_Vim_in_an_xterm) does the same thing in vim.

Answer (score 5):

This is in case controlled by the option `Terminal` | `Features` | `Disable xterm-style mouse reporting` from Putty's configuration dialog. If it's disabled, the mouseclicks are reported, otherwise they're not.

Many curses-like programs like elinks, vim and such also support the mouse in this way, sometimes even including the scroll wheel. Kinda cool, actually. :o)